# How to add a time to an existing timestamp in Postgresql/sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, timestamp

In my table, i changed the column from date to timestamp. At all the existing rows, Postgres added automatically a time to the date, for example:

2020-04-04 --> 2020-04-04 00:00:00

But i want it set to 09:00 (so: 2020-04-04 09:00:00) for all the existing rows.
Does anybody know how to do that?

Here is my code:

```
    ALTER TABLE members ALTER COLUMN joined SET DATA TYPE timestamp;
    ALTER TABLE members ALTER COLUMN joined SET DEFAULT current_timestamp;
--for all existing columns, change timestamp to [entered-date_09:00:00]
```

Comment: Pretty much the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69767308

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add 9 hours:

```
update members
set joined = joined + interval '9' hour
```

Answer (score 2):

`ALTER COLUMN .. SET DATA TYPE .. USING` is what you're looking for:

```
ALTER TABLE members 
  ALTER COLUMN joined SET DATA TYPE timestamp USING joined + '09:00:00'::time;
```

Or using an `UPDATE` in case you already have a timestamp column

```
UPDATE members
SET joined = joined + '09:00:00'::time
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a9227bf8059f0e6833c379309d5b754d)